# How to get a text box value using HREF without POST

Tags: javascript, php

> http://localhost/check.php?date=textbox1&time=textbox2

```
 <a href="http://localhost/check.php?date=textbox1&time=textbox2" onclick="window.open('http://localhost/check.php?date=textbox1&time=textbox2', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=600'); return false;"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

This is my current code, I would like to transfer textbox 1 and textbox 2 value on a GET method. I tried `document.getElementbyId('date')`.value but no luck.

Comment: You question doesn't seems to be clear, please elaborate more of your code!

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I think he's trying to create a dynamic hyperlink by passing textbox values into the URL manually instead of using a form. Basicly he's trying to get the values out of the textbox before they're submit. Though his code makes no sense if that's what's he's trying.. I see your point, lol

Comment: Hi guys. I have 2 textbox (date, time) I want to pass their values to my link when a href link was clicked. *button click transfers to http://localhost/check.php?date=textbox1value&time=textbox2value Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. From what I understand,
you have this...:

```
<input type="text" id="date"/>
<input type="text" id="time"/>
```

...and you want to use these textbox values for request parameters. Try this:

```
function submitDateAndTime() {
  var url = 'http://localhost/check.php?date=';
  url += document.getElementById('date').value;
  url +='&time=';
  url += document.getElementById('time').value;
  // Do whatever you want with the URL here
  // For example, window.open to load in a new window:
  window.open('url');
  // Or use _self if you want to load in the current window
  window.open('url', '_self');
  // Or ajax, etc.
```

and for HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void submitDateAndTime();">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!